# Laravel How to make a POST that handles an array of objects?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Here's the model of the table I'm trying to insert into:

```
  protected $table ="final_schedule";
  public $timestamps = false;

  protected $fillable = [
    'CWID', //varchar
    'CRN', //int
    'Date_Registered'//date
  ];
```

This is the insert function I have now:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Student;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\finalScheduleModel;

class finalScheduleController extends Controller
{
    public function insert(Request $request){
      $finalSchedule = new finalScheduleModel;
      $finalSchedule->CWID=$request->input('CWID');
      $finalSchedule->CRN=$request->input('CRN');
      $finalSchedule->Date_Registered=$request->input('Date_Registered');
      $finalSchedule->save();
    }
}
```

The Route:
`Route::post('insert/', 'Student\finalScheduleController@insert');`

Here's the data I want it to handle:

```
[
    {
    "CWID":"C38475920",
    "CRN":345627,
    "Date_Registered":"2020-04-02"
    },
    {
    "CWID":"C38475920",
    "CRN":678595,
    "Date_Registered":"2020-04-02"
    },
    {
    "CWID":"C38475920",
    "CRN":473876,
    "Date_Registered":"2020-04-02"
    }
]
```

At least I think it is. Is the way the data is structured above the same as this?

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {…}
1: {…}
2: {…}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may even insert several records into the table with a single call to insert

```
$items = $request->all();

$items = [
    [
       "CWID"=>"C38475920",
       "CRN"=>345627,
       "Date_Registered"=>"2020-04-02"
    ],
    [
       "CWID"=>"C38475920",
       "CRN"=>678595,
       "Date_Registered"=>"2020-04-02"
    ],
    [
       "CWID"=>"C38475920",
       "CRN"=>473876,
       "Date_Registered"=>"2020-04-02"
    ]
]

finalScheduleModel::insert($items);
```

or

```
DB::table('final_schedule')->insert($items);
```

Comment: Sweet dude! Thanks a million